# Does Akamai support anycasted origins?

Tags: routes, akamai, bgp, anycast

I wonder if Akamai supports origins with anycast IP addresses?

Or will requests to origins be routed within Akamais networks to just one (almost random) location?

I'd expect Akamai to route the request to the origin closest to the edge server.

Comment: I do not think the question makes much sense in the present form. Origin has nothing to do with Akamai. Origin is your system, and you provide it's address to Akamai. So if you have "anycasted origin" - so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Akamai does support AnyCast IP-addresses for your Origin Server. When the Akamai EdgeServer has to go forward to your origin, it will do a look-up based on IP or hostname you provided.

/akamaimike